# ASP.NET MVC4 - How to save dropdown items after button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have some beginning form where user can enter some basic data like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
```

Now I want to add one additional field to this form where user can choose languages he knows. It needs to be one dropdown list with button on the right side. When user chooses a language from dropdown list and clicks Add button on the right side, name of the language should be displayed below. I'm not sure how to handle this. I've just began learning so it's still a little bit confusing to me.

```
<li>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Language,
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Pro.Web.Models.Data.Languages))))
</li>
```

I've read a couple of tutorials but didn't find anything similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a multi select list which will allow the user to select one or more languages he knows:

```
<li>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(
        model => model.Language,
        Enum
           .GetValues(typeof(Pro.Web.Models.Data.Languages))
           .Cast<Pro.Web.Models.Data.Languages>()
           .Select(x => new SelectListItem 
           { 
               Value = x.ToString(), 
               Text = x.ToString() 
           })
    )
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you. I gave one vote up. It will work for now but I still need some version with button.